# How do I validate data inserted from asp.net to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a web form already connected to SQL Server. I can insert but I don't know how to do the validation to not insert data if the table already has the same information.

How can this process be done?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=hans-pc;Initial Catalog=CntExp;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO PreExp1 (Expe, Usuario) values (@Expe, @Usuario)", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expe", TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", TextBox2.Text);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", Datenow());

    con.Open();

    int insertar = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Response.Write("Inserted" + insertar.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Try insert, hit unique index, handle failure.  Also, you should be explicitly closing your connection after you're done with it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a little broad as there are a lot of different ways to achieve that. You can check if the data exists by querying the database from your code (inside a transaction) or use triggers in the database. SO is more likely to help you at specific coding problems. So you should be more specific what "the same information" means. The semantics may help to decide if you want to validate in your code or at db level.

Comment: @OmarLopez  If your build your table right, with the correct referential integrity then your insert should throw an exception which you can appropriately catch and handle.

Answer (score 0):

You're using Input parameters.  Lines like this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Expe", TextBox1.Text);
```

they're considered Input parameters.  One way to validate your data would be to use an Output parameter.  Something like:

```
SqlParameter outParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@MyParam", sqlDbType.Uniqueidentifier);
outParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Pass that to a Stored Procedure that determines whether or not a record exists, and passes the Boolean "True" or "False" back to your C# code.
Then you can check the value of outParam and determine whether or not you want to continue processing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from having the correct integrity checks in the database, you can apply a WHERE NOT EXISTS sub query.

```
INSERT INTO PreExp1 (Expe, Usuario) 
VALUES (@Expe, @Usuario)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM PreExp1
                    WHERE Expe = @Expe
                    AND Usuario = @Usuario)
```